# Calculating Percentages in R Dataframe based on Total?

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

I currently have a dataframe which looks like this

EDIT NEW UPDATE OF NEW DATAFRAME

```
    Country    Information  Value 
    UK         Cars         50 
    UK         Sheep        20
    UK         Cats         15
    UK         Dogs         10 
    UK         Shoes        3
    UK         Hats         2
    Total                   100
```

Country column is the same repeated 6 times and last row is called Total, Information is just random info and Value are numeric, they do sum to 100 and are in Descending order from highest to lowest

I would like to find a way within R to add a new column (df$Percentage) which calculates the percentage of each row based as a percentage of the Total in the column Value

so for example the new column would have

```
Country    Information  Value     Percentage 
    UK         Cars         50     0.50 (or can be 50%)
    UK         Sheep        20     0.20 
    UK         Cats         15     0.15
    UK         Dogs         10     0.10
    UK         Shoes        3      0.03
    UK         Hats         2      0.02
    Total                   100    1.00 (or nothing here)
```

and so on to reach the end of the dataframe where TOTAL would either be blank (assuming percentage has stopped upto there or would equal 1)

I am fairly new to R so any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Try `df$Percentage <- paste0(df$Value/100*100, "%")`

Answer (score 2):

```
df$percentage <- df$Value/(sum(df$Value)/2)
#results
  Country Information Value percentage
1      UK        Cars    50       0.50
2      UK       Sheep    20       0.20
3      UK        Cats    15       0.15
4      UK        Dogs    10       0.10
5      UK       Shoes     3       0.03
6      UK        Hats     2       0.02
7   Total               100       1.00
```

I divided by 2 the sum because the last line contains already the total of the Value column

---

Edit to provide a reproducible example :

```
structure(list(Country = c("UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", 
"Total"), Information = c("Cars", "Sheep", "Cats", "Dogs", "Shoes", 
"Hats", ""), Value = c(50, 20, 15, 10, 3, 2, 100)), .Names = c("Country", 
"Information", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but i still did not get the correct outcome, any thoughts as to why?, it currently says replacement length is shorter then the orginal

Comment: Could you give us a test dataset e.g. `dput(df)` and copy/paste the results here

Comment: have editied the original post please have a look at the new dataframe thank you

Comment: It would be easier if you provide us with a reproducible dataset as suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: Hi, I have addded the actual dataframe i am using, above is the real dataframe i am using, thank you

Comment: could you post dput results. It's a good practice for R-related question ;)

Comment: Sorry I can't at the moment I am about to go on the move, if you could advise me a best way to calcualuse percentage that would be really helpful

Comment: The command I posted in my answer should work with the dataframe you defined in your question

Comment: It outputs a column of NA

Comment: this should be a fairly sdtright forward thing here, just dividing the values by the total into a new column - i have tried several things but no solution!

Comment: I Guess your Value column are factors. Do df$Value <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Value)) before applying the other function

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I have found the problem, the new dataset has a new 7th row with the value set as NA, which is why i can't apply what you wrote, is there any way to pass over the NA so it works?